# How can I create an abstract class in code, let a blueprint extend it, and give that blueprint back to code to instantiate?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Suppose I want to create an AI class in code that will be used to control a pawn, but I want my designers to be able to modify the behavior using blueprints for rapid iterations.

Suppose I have this in **MyProjectBaseAI.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "EngineMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyProjectBaseAI.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT_API AMyProjectBaseAI : AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public:
    AMyProjectBaseAI(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);

    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;

    void SetGoalPosition(FVector pos);
  
    virtual void DetermineGoalPosition(int32 stateData1, int32 stateData2) = 0;

private:
    FVector goalPosition;
};
```

I would like to make this class abstract and have a blueprint able to implement `DetermineGoalPosition(...);` to call `SetGoalPosition(FVector pos)` depending on their design of the AI.

Then, how can the designers set the implementing class in the inspector so that my C++ code can instantiate it? Suppose I have a class that wants to instantiate the implementing class like this (currently using base class):

```
AMyProjectBaseAI* ai = World->SpawnActor<AMyProjectBaseAI>(...);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Abstract class setup:

1. Use the `Abstract` and `Blueprintable` specifiers in `UCLASS` to mark the class as abstract and blueprintable (although, when you are inheriting from `AActor` or another blueprintable class, the `Blueprintable` specifier is redundant).
2. Use `BlueprintImplementableEvent` in a `UFUNCTION` specifier for `DetermineGoalPosition`. This allows blueprints to implement the function.

Also, **do not declare the function as virtual**, per Unreal's standard since [ver 4.8](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Support/Builds/ReleaseNotes/2015/4_8/index.html):

> New: Removed "virtual" keyword from several engine-level BlueprintImplementableEvents to conform to the new "BlueprintImplementableEvents should not be virtual" standard.

3. Use the `BlueprintCallable` property in a `UFUNCTION` specifier for `SetGoalPosition`. This allows the function to be called from a blueprint.

   ```
    #pragma once

    #include "EngineMinimal.h"
    #include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
    #include "MyProjectBaseAI.generated.h"

    UCLASS(Abstract, Blueprintable)
    class MYPROJECT_API AMyProjectBaseAI : AActor 
    {
        GENERATED_BODY()

    public:
        AMyProjectBaseAI(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);

        virtual void BeginPlay() override;

        virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;

        UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
        void SetGoalPosition(FVector pos);

        UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent)
        void DetermineGoalPosition(int32 stateData1, int32 stateData2);

    private:
        FVector goalPosition;
    };
   ```

## Instantiator setup

4. Then in the header of the class you would like to set the implementing class in the inspector, have a public  `TSubclassOf<AMyProjectBaseAI>` variable with the `EditAnywhere` specifier (or `EditDefaultsOnly` or `EditInstanceOnly` if the subclass should be set only at the blueprint or instance level in the editor):

   ```
    public:
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        TSubclassOf<AMyProjectBaseAI> AIImplementationClass;
   ```
5. And then where you instantiate it, simply use `AIImplementationClass` as the class:

   ```
    AMyProjectBaseAI* ai = World->SpawnActor<AMyProjectBaseAI>(AIImplementationClass);
   ```